# Iterator for type erasure

Tags: c++

Iterator for type erasure

Problem:

In module, there is a class D, defined as

```
class D
{
    std::string s_;
    bool b_;
};
```

The module has a vector of D, e.g. `std::vector<D>`

I want two things:

1. Do not expose the internal data structure. User of the module should
   not know about class D.
2. User of the module can only access the
   vector of D via an iterator.

I have a helper class: `DHelper`, exposing only necessary information, defined as

```
class DHelper
{
public:
   bool b_;
};
```

Module can have the following interface:

```
DHelperIterator MyModule::GetVectorD();
```

Example usage:

```
#include DHelper.h
#include MyModule.h   // class D is hidden from MyModule.h using pimpl

MyModule myModule;
foreach(DHelper& d, myModule.GetVector())
{
    std::cout << d.b_ << std::endl;
}
```

We can see, ideally, `DHelperIterator` deferences type of `DHelper`, but iterating over the vector of D.

Can I ask how to implement `DHelperIterator`? Answer better with source code of both header and cpp files, in addition to example codes ideally.

Comment: DHelper and the iterator should be one entity. Since the users of the iterator only care about the type they recieve (in this case a boolean).

Comment: Also, this isn't really about type erasure...

Comment: both D and DHelper are simplified. Both can have many members, though DHelper is lighter, usually a POCO.